# Problem with PhpStorm and intellisense on shared Angular - Nativescript project

Tags: angular, nativescript, phpstorm

I create my project using the standard guide for sharing project and the command

```
ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics project-name --shared
```

The project creation is done and the webapp and mobile app start correctly if i try to start it.
The problem is about intellisense.
I have installed the Nativescript Plugin and is active.
But when i try to edit Nativescript dedicated file , the editor doesn't recognize the Nativescript source.

I have error like this:
**Class NativeScriptRouterModule is not an Angular Model**

The project is working fine but is without any type of intellisense for Nativescript. For Angular is ok.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of where you are importing that module & how it looks in editor?

Comment: I can't upload image because of my reputation. The imported module are in file  app-routing.module.tns.ts that's the router module for nativescript. You can find the image at this link https://ibb.co/CmQLhXn

Comment: Angular support doesn't consider `module.tns` files and knows nothing about nativescript. Related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-44250

Comment: Ok, i can accept the underline error about modules of nativescript not known by angular, but i lost the intellisense to build tha nativescript component. Ther's no solution about?